# Trying to add my first Chart Web Part, can't get past enabling it

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, chart-web-part, chart

I have SharePoint Foundation 2010 installed.

Following guides such as [this](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/c9fee4de-be27-492f-b1b2-ebe45e66dc13/cant-find-the-chart-web-part-to-use-in-sharepoint-2010-standalone-installed-on-windows-2008-server?forum=sharepointadminprevious), I am trying to enable the Chart Web Part, but I do not see `Microsoft.Office.Server.WebControls.ChartWebPart` as an option to check. In fact, I don't see anything with `Microsoft.Office.Server.*`, if that's a clue. It's probably something simple, but why might I be missing this under Site Settings/Galleries/Web Parts?

For further information, I do see plenty of other options, including similarly named `Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ChartViewWebPart`. When I enable that, it shows up as a Web Part but doesn't give me the option to choose a data source for it.

Answer (score 1):

Chart Web Parts aren't available in SharePoint Foundation 2010, they are available in Enterprise version.. For full feature comparison list, please have a look at [SharePoint 2010 Feature Comparison (SharePoint Foundation 2010 Vs SharePoint 2010 Standard/Enterprise)](http://sharepointpolice.com/blog/2010/05/03/sharepoint-2010-feature-comparison-sharepoint-foundation-2010-vs-sharepoint-2010-standardenterprise/)

However you can use [Fusion Chart Web Parts](http://charts4sharepoint.codeplex.com/) which are free to use CodePlex project and are compatible with SharePoint Foundation 2010..

Comment: @Robert, I know we shouldn't add mark as correct.. But new people usually don't mark and they leave the question open.. :)

Comment: I know the feeling! My tip is to first wait and see, give the user a chance. Then you can use comments to remind the user after some time :)

Comment: As you say.. Aye Aye Sire..